# Javafx 2 native development and distribution dongle

Tags: java, native, dongle

1. Can  Javafx 2 class made secure ? Native files so they are not readable?
2. The native bundling using oracle method - would the code readable ?
3. Is there way of distributing our application using software or hardware (dongle) keys ?

Thanks

Comment: No & No (they can be made natives, and are still readable), Yes, Yes.  Please limit questions to one question per ..question.  Thanks.

Comment: Also note that if you need to ask those questions, in all likelihood, there is **no** need to protect the code.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Sorry I am new here - I will keep this in mind - one question per post. Your second comment - I have written a code and was wondering the best way to protect it.

Comment: Make sensitive information/business logic configurable so it will **NOT be visible** in the code. Then **share** (make open source) the code and protect (**don't share**) configurations.  
By making your code open source you will protect (and improve) it in the best possible way - you will learn more, others may learn from you, others may contribute to you code improving it.